# JUnit test with Maven in a Jenkins plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, jenkins

I have a problem when I tried to run JUnit tests with Maven. For a Jenkins plug-in I wrote a class for test.  For example: I have the class `ConsoleParser` in package *com.jenkins_plugin* in folder *src/main/java*. The JUnit test case is `ConsoleParserTest` in *package com.jenkins_plugin* in folder *src/test*. For running the JUnit test I added the dependency in the pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version> 
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And I ran in cmd the next command: `mvn -Dtest=ConsoleParserTest test`

The problem is that I've got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12:test (default-test) on project swatt_jenkins: No tests were executed!  (Set -
DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

The full *pom.xml* is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <finalName>Jenkins_Plugin</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.526</version>
    </parent>


    <groupId>Jenkins_Plugin</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>hpi</packaging>



    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version> 
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Also, I must mention that with those settings I ran successfully the test but after adding findbugs it crashed. So, I removed findbugs and try to run the test again but the problem that I mentioned appeared. So, can someone explain what I have to do? I tried to add another version of JUnit, Surefire but I had the same problem and I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you please add the code of your testclass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several things:

- add you JUnit classes to `src/test/java` not `src/test`
- for your JUnit class use the scope "test"

E.g.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version> 
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also I recommend to manage your repositories in a repository manager such as Nexus, not in your POM:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html